# how to specialize this template function

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction, function-templates

I have a class with a templated method and I want that method to take arguments as const reference. Something like this:

```
//UART.hh

class UART
{
    UART();
    ~UART();
    template<typename T>
    bool initHandler(const T &);
};
```

I need to pass the initHandler method a pointer to a struct as argument.

```
//supposing "USART_TypeDef" to be a struct and "USART1" a pointer to that struct,
//I need to make the following call:

initHandler(USART1);
```

So I though I was OK to specialize the initHandler method like this:

```
//UART.hh

class UART
{
    UART();
    ~UART();
    template<typename T>
    bool initHandler(const T &);
};

template<> bool UART::initHandler<USART_TypeDef*>(const USART_TypeDef *);
```

Howeve, I get the following compile time error:

```
error: template-id 'initHandler<USART_TypeDef*>' for 'bool UART::initHandler(const USART_TypeDef*)' does not match any template declaration

template<> bool UART::initHandler<USART_TypeDef*>(const USART_TypeDef *);
                ^~~~
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions and comments.

Comment: The parameter has to be `USART_TypeDef * const &` in order to match

Comment: Can you not call it as `initHandler(*USART1);` and let the parameter stay a reference?

Comment: @UnholySheep do you mean like changing the specialization to "template<> bool UART::initHandler<USART_TypeDef*>(USART_TypeDef * const&)" or are you trying to say that "USART1" has to be of type "USART_TypeDef * const &" ?

Comment: @BoP I'd rather not having to de-reference the pointer to be able to call the function with it

Comment: The former, since the base template requires a `const T &` (which is the same as `T const &`) and `T` is `USART_TypeDef *` the only way to match the base is to have the specialized function accept a `USART_TypeDef * const &` as argument